# ¿Cómo fijar un card-footer al final de una card? CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Las cards estan dentro de un carousel, fijadas con ese height y que no se debe modificar.

La idea es que el footer quede fijo al final y que el card-header sea autoajustable dependiendo de la descripción.

===> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucasmorettii/7pfxg9qz/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el tamaño del card es fijo puedes intentar con

```
.fa-tags {
  min-height: 3rem;
}
```

De esta manera haces que el block tenga un mínimo de X tamaño para contener el texto y luego venga el footer.

Otra opción es:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.card-foter {
  /* display: bottom; */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

El problema puede ser que si no controlas el tamaño del texto de .fa-tags pueda superponerse al footer.